# Can IOCTL be used in sending custom input to a Driver

Tags: c, driver, ioctl

Sorry If this is a noob question, but I'm developing a software "add on" for a game. I'm doing this through a driver simply because the anti-cheat doesn't support ring 0 detection. I haven't seen much info on how IOCTL can be used and i was wondering if you can send custom inputs like process ids and other information that may change or is it all set in stone like a switch function or something. Once again sorry for noob question.

Comment: sorry for terrible grammar its 4 in the morning and ive been up all night

Comment: There are no rules, IOCTLs let you do anything you want.

Comment: That's the whole point of `ioctl`. It's a simple, generic interface that lets you add any driver-specific operation you want when the standard I/O operations don't fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate with a kernel-mode device driver via IOCTL using the `DeviceIoControl` Win32 API routine. This routine internally calls `NtDeviceIoControlFile (NTDLL)` which performs a system call to get `NtDeviceIoControlFile (NTOSKRNL)` executed.

The `DeviceIoControl` routine is documented at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx

The kernel-mode device driver will have a prerequisite to fulfill: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/named-device-objects

> I haven't seen much info on how IOCTL can be used and i was wondering if you can send custom inputs like process ids and other information

The answer is yes, you can send custom buffers via IOCTL. You can also receive an output buffer back from your kernel-mode device driver to the user-mode application which initiated the IOCTL operation - this is optional of course.

If you need to send multiple pieces of information at the same time, consider using a structure.

I also recommend you read the following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/methods-for-accessing-data-buffers